# docker registry:2.0 local storage

Tags: docker-registry

I can't get docker registry:2.0 to save files to local storage.
Tried

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v "/home/azureuser:/tmp/registry-dev" registry:2.0
docker run -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE=filesystem" -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/tmp/registry" -p 5000:5000 -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/tmp/registry registry:2.0
```

and many other alternatives.

It doesn't allow me to push anything.
If I just `docker run -p 5000:5000 registry:2.0` 
I can push files but it uses my RAM. When it gets down to 100MB it doesn't allow me to push any more files.

Any help or pointing in the right direction will be highly appreciated. I don't know what and where to read any more.

Best Regards,
Costi

Answer (score 1):

Found that if I run docker --privileged it will write in the local disk. So it's a permission issue

Comment: docker run -p 5000:5000 --privileged -d -v "/home/user:/tmp/registry-dev" registry:2.0 should do the job